# what does the () stands for in the property definition?

Tags: .net, vb.net, syntax, properties

I noticed in the code base I have to read that sometimes property definition includes an empty (). What's the meaning of that? And it has nothing to do with arrays.

For example :

```
Public Property TotalPages() As Integer
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know it seems strange (well to us C#'ers) but properties can have parameters in VB.NET.

So you can have

```
Public Class Student
    Private ReadOnly _scores(9) As Integer

    ' An indexed Score property
    Public Property Score(ByVal index As Integer) As _
        Integer
        Get
            Return _scores(index)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _scores(index) = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _score As Integer

    ' A straightforward property
    Public Property Score() As _
        Integer
        Get
            Return _score
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _score = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

Public Class Test
    Public Sub Test()

        Dim s As New Student

        ' use an indexed property
        s.Score(1) = 1

        ' using a standard property   
        ' these two lines are equivalent
        s.Score() = 1
        s.Score = 1

    End Sub
End Class
```

So your declaration of

```
Public Property TotalPages() As Integer
```

Is a straightforward non-indexed property, e.g. with no parameters.

Comment: () on properties indicate an array.  In this particular instance it declares an array of integers.  Interesting tidbit in VB, Public Property TotalPages() as Integer  is the same as Public Property TotalPages as Integer()

Comment: @RobertBeaubien: No, it doesn't declare an array of integers, unless you put the parentheses at the end.

Answer (score 5):

It shows that the property takes no arguments: that it's not an indexed property.

An *indexed property* has one or more indexes. This allows a property to exhibit array-like qualities. For example, look at the following class:

```
  Class Class1  
   Private m_Names As String() = {"Ted", "Fred", "Jed"} 
    ' an indexed property. 
    Readonly Property Item(Index As Integer) As String 
     Get 
      Return m_Names(Index) 
     End Get 
   End Property  
End Class
```

From the client side, you can access the Item property with the following code:

```
Dim obj As New Class1 
Dim s1 String s1 = obj.Item(0)
```

Indexed property explanation from [MSDN magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301731.aspx)